# Cannot download templates in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm unable to download templates from Microsoft Word 2016. I can download them just fine from Excel and PowerPoint.

**Error message:**

> Something went wrong while downloading your template.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open Word.
2. Navigate to: [ File > New ]
3. Click on any template.
4. A dialog appears containing additional information about the template. Click "Create".
5. An error message appears: "Something went wrong while downloading your template."

**Troubleshooting attempts:**

- Many people online have reported that this problem is caused by an incorrect version of Visio being installed (32-bit instead of 64-bit, or vice versa). However, Visio is not installed on my computer.
- I can download templates from Excel and PowerPoint without issue.
- I repaired my Office 2016 installation, but this had no effect.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to download templates from official website: https://templates.office.com/?legRedir=true&CTT=97&CorrelationId=df73ed64-739e-4895-a935-6add56d1482d&omkt=en-USac

Comment: Thanks @Lee. That's a good workaround, but I'd like to be able to download them from Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to install the July Update for office 2016 (KB4464582) along with the July 2, 2019, update for Word 2016 (KB4475521).

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this issue myself with Windows 7 and Windows 10 pcs at work. After troubleshooting this yesterday and today, I found the cause (at least in our case). The cause was a recent windows update, [KB4464596](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464596/description-of-the-security-update-for-word-2016-june-11-2019) to be specific.

[Image of the installed KB4464596 on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFwal.png)

Once I uninstalled this update on my test Windows 10 pc, I didn't have to reboot the machine and I was able to immediately download templates successfully now.

As such try uninstalling KB4464596 and see if it fixes your issue too.